# How to add sencha chart 2 with a sencha touch 2 project using sencha architect

Tags: extjs, sencha-touch-2, sencha-architect, sencha-charts

I am working on a mobile Sencha Touch 2 application and am using Sencha Architect to do the UI and stuff. I also require charts in my application. Is there a way for me to integrate Sencha Charts 2 with Sencha Architect.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yesterday Sencha announced Sencha Touch 2.1:

> "We’ve integrated the new
>   Touch Charts in to Architect, so building mobile data visualizations
>   is as easy as drag and drop."

You can check their blog [here](http://www.sencha.com/blog/introducing-sencha-touch-2-1-and-more), scroll down to "Sencha Architect Updated" where you found a video about Architect and Touch Charts.